# LARAVEL Argument 1 passed to ... Must be of the type array, int given

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to store an entry into a database but I get this error.

> " Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, int given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\im-stuff\test\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php on line 869 "

```
request()->validate(['description' => 'required']);
$project->addTask(compact('description'));
```

Ok, so this does work, but next and better version doesn't.

```
$attributes = request()->validate(['description' => 'required']);
$project->addTask($attributes);
```

So this is the model which is being used.

```
public function tasks()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
}

public function addTask($description)
{
    $this->tasks()->create(compact('description'));
}
```

At this point I am lost and really don't understand.

Comment: Laravel stack trace should tell what in your code is being called for the error to be thrown. Show us that. Also, dump `$attributes` and give us the contents.

Comment: @Script47 

array:1 [▼
  "description" => "hjk"
]

Comment: please try: $this->tasks()->create($description);

Comment: why are you using `compact` you are saving the record to database not passing it to view so don't use `compact` instead it should be `$this->tasks()->create($description);`

Comment: @dparoli that worked, thanks! I wish I would know why though.

Comment: @SalmanZafar so compact is passing to the view only?

Comment: @beat yes never use `compact` when you are saving record to db only use it for passing data to view from controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why are you using `compact` when you are saving the record to database instead as i mentioned in my comment it should be like this simple and easy:

```
public function addTask($description)
{
    $this->tasks()->create($description);
}
```

[here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) you can find the working of `compact`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should try to pass the `attributes` array directly to the `create()` function, e.g.:

```php
public function addTask($description)
{
    $this->tasks()->create($description);
}
```

[Compact](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) creates an array containing the variables passed, in your case:

```php
print_r(compact('description'));
Array
(
    [description] => your_array_of_attributes
)
```

So with `compact()` you are encapsulating your attributes array in another array giving them the key `'description'`.

The `compact()` function is very useful when you want to pass data to the view, instead of writing this:

```php
view('materials.index', ['materials'=>$materials, 'users'=>$users]);
```

You can write:

```php
view('materials.index', compact('materials', 'users'));
```